# How to get url status whether it is opening new tab or it redirecting by using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

Any one can tell me how to get `URL status` whether it is opening new tab or it redirecting by using `Selenium web driver.`

Comment: I don't understand this question. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You mean header status (200, 302, 404) ? Selenium can't do this. There are a lot of tools that is checking your web app on broken urls and other statuses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you're asking how to tell whether a new tab has been created as a result of some action - you can always get the list of currently opened tabs using `driver.getWindowHandles()` method.

You can switch between tabs then using `driver.switchTo().window(oneOfWindowHandles)`.